# SVG animation bug in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari, amcharts4

I've been trying to animate a path in an SVG so it looks like it is being drawn, but have been running into issues in Safari, both on Mac and iOS. Works well on all other browsers I've tried. I'm using amCharts4 to create the SVG

My intention is to have the line draw from start to finish over a couple of seconds. In Firefox and Chrome it animates as intended:
[How it appears in Firefox mid animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr1Ea.png)

But in Safari (Mac or iOS) it seems to pick random positions to start the path:
[How it appears in Safari mid animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCNT5.png)

The CSS I'm using to effect this animation is:

```
#amchart {
    width : 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
    height : 500px;
}
#amchart .amcharts-animateLine1,
#amchart .amcharts-animateLine2,
#amchart .amcharts-animateLine3 {
    stroke-dasharray: 1;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: am-draw;
       -moz-animation-name: am-draw;
         -o-animation-name: am-draw;
            animation-name: am-draw;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
       -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 15s;
       -moz-animation-duration: 15s;
         -o-animation-duration: 15s;
            animation-duration: 15s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: forwards;
       -moz-animation-direction: forwards;
         -o-animation-direction: forwards;
            animation-direction: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes am-draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes am-draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes am-draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes am-draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

When I first encountered the error, I thought setting pathlength="1" to the path in question would solve the issue.

I've created a sandbox so I can play around with the CSS. I just dumped the HTML amCharts rendered into it:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/justinresources/pen/ExOWzNv)

I'm pretty new to CSS animations and SVGs. This is my first question on Stack Overflow, so please correct me if there is anything else I need to add and I'll edit the question.